# Mysql to Oracle rewrite different results

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have re-written a query from Mysql to oracle whereas Mysql is giving me one row and oracle gives multiples just wondering why ?

**Mysql Query**

```
select  me.col1,
        me.col2,
        me.col3,
        min(col3) as me_col3 ,
        group_concat(col2) col4,
from
    my_sql_table me
group by me.col2
order by col3
```

**Rewrite into Oracle**

```
select  
        me.col1,
        me.col2,
        me.col3,
        min(col3) over (partition by episode_id order by col3) as me_col3 ,
        LISTAGG(col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col3) over (partition by col2)
from
    my_sql_table me
group by me.col1,me.col2,me.col3
order by col3
```

Any idea how to rewrite that query so Mysql and Oracle give the same results?

---

Did some research and found that if i remove the `group_concat` and `listagg` I get the same results in Mysql and Oracle.
But if I add the `group_concat` back then the result varies between Mysql and Oracle.

Comment: The query will fail in Oracle with ORA-00979: Not a GROUP BY expression. Why don't you give us a working example?

Comment: What happens if you change the GROUP BY on the MySQL query to include col1, col2, and col3?  Do the results then match?  If so, the issue is the incomplete GROUP BY which MySQL allows but Oracle does not.

Comment: Bob Yes if i add the columns col1,col2,col3 the results do match and i am not sure how to get out of this any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Cause the mysql `GROUP BY` does not work as the `ANSI SQL` `GROUP BY`, which Oracle uses.

In `ANSI SQL`, you have to put all the fields present in the `SELECT` statement which are not in an aggregate function (`MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, etc.) in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Mysql makes a "magic" (sometimes fine, sometimes... suprising) grouping, even if you don't put all the fields in the `GROUP BY` clause.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

By the way, I'm really suprised that your second query works in Oracle.

**EDIT**

Ok with your correction.

Now, imagine you have a table like that

```
id  name    description category
1   n1      d1          1
2   n2      d2          1
3   n2      d3          2
```

if you 
select id, name ,description, category

and group by category

MySQL will give you two rows

```
1, n1, d1, 1 // or 2, n2, d2, 1 : you can't really be sure of what you'll get for non grouped fields
3, n2, d3, 2
```

with Oracle you need 
group by id, name, description, category
So the distinct values of id, name, description and category will return distinct rows
And you will get the 3 rows.

To get something like Mysql, you can either use `AGGREGATE` functions on the fields that you don't want to group on

```
SELECT MIN(id), MIN(name), MIN (description) category
from xxx
GROUP BY category
```

or use a subquery.

Comment: sorry added the other columns for oracle query

Comment: @jhon.smith ok , I understand better. I put some more explanations.

Comment: No Joy after adding the group_concat to the query mix mysql returns different value and oracle returns different result

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not force all no aggregate columns to be part of Group by clause.